# check my xml response

Tags: xml, string, response

Can someone check a xml reply string.  User said it is not XML compatible and has bad header. When I do a view source, I see this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response><task_no_added>54</task_no_added><errorMessage></errorMessage></response>
```

http://itpscan.info/XML/add_item.php

Here is header info found in firebug...

```
Response Headersview source
Date    Sun, 03 Oct 2010 22:50:03 GMT
Server  Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.13
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/html
Request Headersview source
Host    itpscan.info
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Referer http://xxxxxx.info/XML/add_item.php
```

Addition:
I tried adding a xml header, we will see if that works now...

```
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");  
$xml_writer = new XMLWriter();
$xml_writer->openMemory();
$xml_writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8', 'yes');
$xml_writer->startElement('response');
```

Comment: When a user gives you such a bad error report, hand it back to them and tell them to give you specifics.

Comment: they say something in HTTP header is tripping up their XML reader. Also standalone was a problem, but resolved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid XML. You can [verify it yourself here](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp).

Your user's software may be tripped up by the header's `standalone` attribute, which is uncommon, but [legal](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-rmd):

> Markup declarations can affect the content of the document, as passed from an XML processor to an application; examples are attribute defaults and entity declarations. The **standalone document declaration**, which may appear as a component of the XML declaration, signals whether or not there are such declarations [...]

You can just remove it, or convince your serializer to not generate it, if your user is implacable.

**EDIT**: Looking at the HTTP headers, I'd try a *Content-Type* of `text/xml` rather than `text/html` (assuming that the XML you posted is all you're sending in the body).

Comment: @hank: Where, in the tinyurl? I don't follow URL redirectors from unverified users - no offense intended. Try posting the headers in your question body.

Comment: no offense taken.  I posted headers as seen in firebug.  Maybe the content type is wrong?

Comment: @hank: Looks like it. I think you want `text/xml`.